# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0.000000' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a code

```
select CONVERT(NUMERIC, 
  CASE ISNULL(FLEXFIELD4,'') WHEN '' THEN 0 
  ELSE FLEXFIELD4 END )      
FROM DEIT_INDENT_DTL_INBOUND_RXL WHERE IND_INDENT_NO='NEE15SR000003'
```

which is giving me error

> "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0.000000' to
>   data type int."

i am unable to find the solution.

help me..

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Why not use `ISNULL(FLEXFIELD4, 0)` instead of a `CASE` statement?

Answer (score 2):

In your code I see a `CONVERT(NUMERIC,...)` but **not** a `CONVERT(INT,...)`.  So where is the converting to data type int happening?

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, N'0.0000')    -- Conversion failed message
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC, N'0.0000')-- Converts to 0
```

For what it is worth, if you do the following, you also get a '0'.

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(NUMERIC, N'0.0000'))
```

It seems that FLEXFIELD4 is NVARCHAR. If there is some other conversion involved that your code does not show, then that might clarify the issue.